# Step by Step Substitution

Tags: haskell, substitution

I have problems in understanding the following function

```
lines :: String -> [String]
lines ""        = []
lines ('\n':cs) = "": lines cs
lines (c:cs)    = case lines cs of
                   [] -> [[c]]
                   (l:ls) -> (c:l):ls
```

I want to understand what the function is doing when it is called by `"f\no"`. I am looking for a tool that shows every substitution step for a better understanding of the function. I tried it manually (and got a solution while writing this post) but I am not sure if I am correct.

```
lines ('f':"\no")  = case lines "\no" of
                      [] -> [['f']]
                      (l:ls) -> ('f':l):ls
```

--> `lines "\no"`

```
lines ('\n':"o")   = "": lines "o"
```

--> `lines "o"`

```
lines ('o':"")     = case lines "" of
                      [] -> [['o']]
                      (l:ls) -> ('o':l):ls
```

--> `lines ""`

```
lines ""           = []
```

--> return `[]`

```
lines ('o':"")     = case [] of
                      [] -> [['o']]
lines ('o':"")     = [['o']]
```

--> return `["o"]`

```
lines ('\n':cs)     = "": ["o"]
```

-->return `"": ["o"]`

```
lines ('f':"\no")  = case "":["o"] of
                      (l:ls) -> ('f':l):ls

lines ('f':"\no")  = ('f':""):["o"]
                   = ["f", "o"]
```

Is that right?

Comment: it looks good yeah - for the tool: you could basically use the debugger in GHCi to step through it ;)

Comment: btw: this kind of question is really rather unfortunate for SO - as you can see you only get answers like "Yes I think so"  - this is why I gonna vote to close this

Comment: Maybe https://stevekrouse.github.io/hs.js/ can help, but I don't know exactly how much Haskell is supported by that tool.

Comment: This site is great but seems to be not capable to interprete this code: "Expected " ", "(", "=", "[", [0-9] or [A-Za-z] but "\"" found."

Answer (score 2):

I tried to figure it out in my head without reading your solution. When I was half through I got a headache and started further reading your post. As far as I got all was in accord with what you wrote. The remaining part was nicely explained by you.

From what I can tell and to answer your question, yes, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use Debug.Trace.trace in your code to trace calls and return values:

```
trace :: String -> a -> a
```

For example:

```
import Debug.Trace

traceL l t v = trace (replicate l ' '++t) v  

lines' :: String -> Int -> [String]
lines' ""        l = traceL l"lines \"\" = " $ traceL l "[]" []
lines' ('\n':cs) l = 
    let v = (traceL l ("lines ('\\n':"++show cs++") = ") ""):lines' cs (l+1)
    in  (traceL l (show v) v)

lines' (c:cs) l = 
    let v = case traceL l ("lines ("++show c++":"++show cs++") = ") $ lines' cs (l+1) of [] -> [[c]];(x:xs) -> (c:x):xs
    in (traceL l (show v) v)
```

The l parameter is the level of call.
Hope it will help

Comment: Wow. This is a bit overwhelming for my basic knowledge. But I tried it on my ghci and got the following error-message: Error: "parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)".

Comment: I corrected it but had to put the case statement on a single line.

Answer (score 1):

nu, the recursive calls to `lines` will stack so the expression will be processed from right to left, returning the arguments to the earlier calls. Something like:

```
"o" will pass a "" as cs returning a []

'o' will then become ["o"] returning a (l:ls)

"\n" will become a "", cons'd into the ["o"], returning ["","o"], another (l:ls)

'f' will finally become the c in (c:l):ls meaning ('f':""):["o"] producing ["f","o"]
```